# How to migrate some packages from conan.io/center to corporate artifactory

Tags: artifactory, conan

We have a bunch of conan packages (boost, yaml-cpp, ...) that are currently retrieved from conan.io/center. We have to migrate them to our corporate artifactory, after sending them through security analysis (IT strong requirement). What is the proper way to do that ? I tried to use Conan install, and after conan upload (after having done a conan remote update_ref), but it does not seem to do the job: I had missing patches files when building our product due to the yaml-cpp package dependency.

Conan download should do the job, but I don't see how to download only the relevant bits (ie: linux, gcc, etc...).

Have any idea ?

Best regards,

Jean-Pierre

Comment: Isn't it a requirement to build the binaries from source in your own infrastructure? It is very typical that a IT strong concern on security request this. It is very possible to build the packages you want from source in your infra, cloning the https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index repo and doing ``conan create . version@`` of the packages you want there. Otherwise, ``conan download --package pkgid`` allows you to specify the individual pkg-id you want to retrieve. But ``conan install`` could be better, because it also fetch dependencies.

Comment: We don't have to build everything from source - the requirement is that everything that we put on our artifactory, or that we use during the build process must come from safe orgin (ie: corporate artifactory, canonical repositories,...). That being said, my first try was to conan install from conancenter/ scan the conan data folder / conan upload to artifactory. But when I used these packages, I ran into troubles, due to missing "patches files". I will try downloading only the needed packages.